# horizontal and vertical smooth scroll snap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gsap, scrolltrigger

I'm just wondering if I can get a horizontal smooth scroll snap in somewhere between the vertical scroll snap?

This one is what I'm working with so far - https://codepen.io/tarunpatnayak/pen/rNYvvQb

I'm trying to include something like this in between the vertical scroll - https://codepen.io/tarunpatnayak/pen/OJOQXwp

Can someone please help me achieving this?

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollToPlugin);

let sections = gsap.utils.toArray(".panel");

function goToSection(i) {
  gsap.to(window, {
    scrollTo: {
      y: i * innerHeight,
      autoKill: false,
      ease: "Power3.easeInOut"
    },
    duration: 0.85
  });
}

ScrollTrigger.defaults({
  // markers: true
});

sections.forEach((eachPanel, i) => {
  // const mainAnim = gsap.timeline({ paused: true });

  ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: eachPanel,
    onEnter: () => goToSection(i)
  });

  ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: eachPanel,
    start: "bottom bottom",
    onEnterBack: () => goToSection(i)
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.panel p {
  font-size: 6vw;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<section class="panel red">
  <p>This is page 1</p>
</section>
<section class="panel green">
  <p>This is page 2</p>
</section>
<section class="panel blue">
  <p>This is page 3</p>
</section>
<section class="panel orange">
  <p>This is page 4</p>
</section>
<section class="panel red">
  <p>This is page 5</p>
</section>
<section class="panel green">
  <p>This is page 6</p>
</section>
<section class="panel blue">
  <p>This is page 7</p>
</section>
<section class="panel orange">
  <p>This is page 8</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi, have you ever seen Owl Carousel, I highly recomend it

Comment: Also, I'm not 100% sure I understand your question. You want to include horizontal scroll snap in vertical scroll snap? You can't have both in one item. either it needs to go vertical or it needs to go horizontal. Please make your intention more clear. What is the end goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/demos.html